# iPhone XML Parsing problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am trying to extract the title from this xml:

```
<entry>
...
 <title type="html">Some title</title>
 <published>2011-02-07T00:04:16Z</published>
 <updated>2011-02-07T00:04:16Z</updated>
...
</entry>
```

in the NSXMLParsing's `didStartElement` code:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) 
 {
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 }

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
 {
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }
```

in `foundCharacters`:

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
{
    [currentTitle appendString:string];
}
```

in `didEndElement`:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"])
{
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];

    [currentElement release];
    currentElement = nil;
    [item release];
    item = nil;

}
```

The problem is that for some reason when it gets to the `didEndElement` the `currentTitle` has got the three node's content, so its:

> Some
>   title2011-02-07T00:04:16Z2011-02-07T00:04:16Z

I don't get why its picking up the published and updated node and appending them to the title string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `currentElement` to `@"title"` in `didStartElement:` but you never unset it.  The first element in this particular XML file is `title`, so you set `currentElement` and for every `foundCharacters:` thereafter you append them.  Change `didStartElement:` to:

```
currentElement = [elementName copy];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) 
 {
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 }

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
 {
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to didEndElement:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    [currentElement release];
    currentElement = nil;
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to add that bit, I do have that in already - edited my code

Answer (score 0):

define 
NSMutableString *strFoundCharacters; in class method set property and synthesize it.
then in

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *) string {
    NSString *strAppend = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([strAppend length] > 0) {
        [self.strFoundCharacters appendString:string];
    }
}
```

make nil to strfoundcharacter in

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{


if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] ) {
        self.currentTitle = self.strFoundCharacters;
    }
    [self.strFoundCharacters setString:@""];

    }
```

i think it will work